# Element input type= text cannot input Vietnamese

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, datatables

I'm using individual column searching (text inputs) of datatables. There was an error that could not enter the search in Vietnamese but in input text "Search:" can input Vietnamese ! [You can access the link to try](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html)

Note: coppy and paste it okey but i'm input is wrong example quyết -> quye·t· (i'm using Telex)

[in here can input Vietnamese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpZU5.png)

[in here can not input Vietnamese,input is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImMWr.png)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );
    $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );



$( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
    if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
        table
            .column(i)
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    }
} );
```

} );

```
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fixedHeader`-plugin for datatables can mess up the focus of elements. When you change the content of the inputs, an search on the columns will be performed. This search also seems to trigger the `_modeChange`-method of the `fixedHeader`-plugin and the currently active/focuesd element will loose its focus. The `_modeChange`-method tries to remember the current element that has the focus, blur it and in the end re-apply that focus to the element. This makes the input fields unusable for some characters like `â, ñ, é, ...` which need several keypresses to create/input.

Here are some solutions i can think of:

1. You can remove/disable the `fixedHeader`.
2. You could try to change parts of the `fixedHeader`-plugin.
3. You could try to replace any telex-combinations in the input-field prior the search when a key was pressed. (`aa` to `â`, ...)
4. Or you could try to prevent a search if a modifier-char/key was pressed. (But i think this is not suitable for the Telex-Variant)

**Example: Disabled fixedHeader.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
  $('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#example thead');
  $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function(i){
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />');
 
    $('input', this).on('keyup change', function(event){
      if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
        table
        .column(i)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
      }
    });
  });
 
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    orderCellsTop: true
  });
});
```

```css
thead input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"> <thead> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Position</th> <th>Office</th> <th>Age</th> <th>Start date</th> <th>Salary</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>Tiger Nixon</td> <td>System Architect</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>61</td> <td>2011/04/25</td> <td>$320,800</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Garrett Winters</td> <td>Accountant</td> <td>Tokyo</td> <td>63</td> <td>2011/07/25</td> <td>$170,750</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Ashton Cox</td> <td>Junior Technical Author</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>66</td> <td>2009/01/12</td> <td>$86,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Cedric Kelly</td> <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>22</td> <td>2012/03/29</td> <td>$433,060</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Airi Satou</td> <td>Accountant</td> <td>Tokyo</td> <td>33</td> <td>2008/11/28</td> <td>$162,700</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Brielle Williamson</td> <td>Integration Specialist</td> <td>New York</td> <td>61</td> <td>2012/12/02</td> <td>$372,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Herrod Chandler</td> <td>Sales Assistant</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>59</td> <td>2012/08/06</td> <td>$137,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Rhona Davidson</td> <td>Integration Specialist</td> <td>Tokyo</td> <td>55</td> <td>2010/10/14</td> <td>$327,900</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Colleen Hurst</td> <td>Javascript Developer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>39</td> <td>2009/09/15</td> <td>$205,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Sonya Frost</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>23</td> <td>2008/12/13</td> <td>$103,600</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jena Gaines</td> <td>Office Manager</td> <td>London</td> <td>30</td> <td>2008/12/19</td> <td>$90,560</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Quinn Flynn</td> <td>Support Lead</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>22</td> <td>2013/03/03</td> <td>$342,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Charde Marshall</td> <td>Regional Director</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>36</td> <td>2008/10/16</td> <td>$470,600</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Haley Kennedy</td> <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td> <td>London</td> <td>43</td> <td>2012/12/18</td> <td>$313,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td> <td>Regional Director</td> <td>London</td> <td>19</td> <td>2010/03/17</td> <td>$385,750</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michael Silva</td> <td>Marketing Designer</td> <td>London</td> <td>66</td> <td>2012/11/27</td> <td>$198,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Paul Byrd</td> <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td> <td>New York</td> <td>64</td> <td>2010/06/09</td> <td>$725,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Gloria Little</td> <td>Systems Administrator</td> <td>New York</td> <td>59</td> <td>2009/04/10</td> <td>$237,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Bradley Greer</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>London</td> <td>41</td> <td>2012/10/13</td> <td>$132,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Dai Rios</td> <td>Personnel Lead</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>35</td> <td>2012/09/26</td> <td>$217,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jenette Caldwell</td> <td>Development Lead</td> <td>New York</td> <td>30</td> <td>2011/09/03</td> <td>$345,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Yuri Berry</td> <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td> <td>New York</td> <td>40</td> <td>2009/06/25</td> <td>$675,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Caesar Vance</td> <td>Pre-Sales Support</td> <td>New York</td> <td>21</td> <td>2011/12/12</td> <td>$106,450</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Doris Wilder</td> <td>Sales Assistant</td> <td>Sidney</td> <td>23</td> <td>2010/09/20</td> <td>$85,600</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Angelica Ramos</td> <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td> <td>London</td> <td>47</td> <td>2009/10/09</td> <td>$1,200,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Gavin Joyce</td> <td>Developer</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>42</td> <td>2010/12/22</td> <td>$92,575</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jennifer Chang</td> <td>Regional Director</td> <td>Singapore</td> <td>28</td> <td>2010/11/14</td> <td>$357,650</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Brenden Wagner</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>28</td> <td>2011/06/07</td> <td>$206,850</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Fiona Green</td> <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>48</td> <td>2010/03/11</td> <td>$850,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Shou Itou</td> <td>Regional Marketing</td> <td>Tokyo</td> <td>20</td> <td>2011/08/14</td> <td>$163,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle House</td> <td>Integration Specialist</td> <td>Sidney</td> <td>37</td> <td>2011/06/02</td> <td>$95,400</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Suki Burks</td> <td>Developer</td> <td>London</td> <td>53</td> <td>2009/10/22</td> <td>$114,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Prescott Bartlett</td> <td>Technical Author</td> <td>London</td> <td>27</td> <td>2011/05/07</td> <td>$145,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Gavin Cortez</td> <td>Team Leader</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>22</td> <td>2008/10/26</td> <td>$235,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Martena Mccray</td> <td>Post-Sales support</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>46</td> <td>2011/03/09</td> <td>$324,050</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Unity Butler</td> <td>Marketing Designer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>47</td> <td>2009/12/09</td> <td>$85,675</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Howard Hatfield</td> <td>Office Manager</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>51</td> <td>2008/12/16</td> <td>$164,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Hope Fuentes</td> <td>Secretary</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>41</td> <td>2010/02/12</td> <td>$109,850</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Vivian Harrell</td> <td>Financial Controller</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>62</td> <td>2009/02/14</td> <td>$452,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Timothy Mooney</td> <td>Office Manager</td> <td>London</td> <td>37</td> <td>2008/12/11</td> <td>$136,200</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td> <td>Director</td> <td>New York</td> <td>65</td> <td>2008/09/26</td> <td>$645,750</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Olivia Liang</td> <td>Support Engineer</td> <td>Singapore</td> <td>64</td> <td>2011/02/03</td> <td>$234,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Bruno Nash</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>London</td> <td>38</td> <td>2011/05/03</td> <td>$163,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td> <td>Support Engineer</td> <td>Tokyo</td> <td>37</td> <td>2009/08/19</td> <td>$139,575</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Thor Walton</td> <td>Developer</td> <td>New York</td> <td>61</td> <td>2013/08/11</td> <td>$98,540</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Finn Camacho</td> <td>Support Engineer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>47</td> <td>2009/07/07</td> <td>$87,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Serge Baldwin</td> <td>Data Coordinator</td> <td>Singapore</td> <td>64</td> <td>2012/04/09</td> <td>$138,575</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Zenaida Frank</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>New York</td> <td>63</td> <td>2010/01/04</td> <td>$125,250</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Zorita Serrano</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>56</td> <td>2012/06/01</td> <td>$115,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jennifer Acosta</td> <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>43</td> <td>2013/02/01</td> <td>$75,650</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Cara Stevens</td> <td>Sales Assistant</td> <td>New York</td> <td>46</td> <td>2011/12/06</td> <td>$145,600</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Hermione Butler</td> <td>Regional Director</td> <td>London</td> <td>47</td> <td>2011/03/21</td> <td>$356,250</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Lael Greer</td> <td>Systems Administrator</td> <td>London</td> <td>21</td> <td>2009/02/27</td> <td>$103,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jonas Alexander</td> <td>Developer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>30</td> <td>2010/07/14</td> <td>$86,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Shad Decker</td> <td>Regional Director</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>51</td> <td>2008/11/13</td> <td>$183,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michael Bruce</td> <td>Javascript Developer</td> <td>Singapore</td> <td>29</td> <td>2011/06/27</td> <td>$183,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Donna Snider</td> <td>Customer Support</td> <td>New York</td> <td>27</td> <td>2011/01/25</td> <td>$112,000</td> </tr> </tbody> <tfoot> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Position</th> <th>Office</th> <th>Age</th> <th>Start date</th> <th>Salary</th> </tr> </tfoot> </table>
```

**Example: Prevent search when some modifier-keys are pressed.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
  $('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#example thead');
  $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function(i){
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />');
 
    var modifiers = [16, 17, 18, 192, 160]; // shift, ctrl, alt, ´, ^
    $('input', this).on('keyup change', function(event){
      if (modifiers.includes(event.keyCode)) {
        return false;
      }
      if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
        table
        .column(i)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
      }
    });
  });
 
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    orderCellsTop: true,
    fixedHeader: true
  });
});
```

```css
thead input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"> <thead> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Position</th> <th>Office</th> <th>Age</th> <th>Start date</th> <th>Salary</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>Tiger Nixon</td> <td>System Architect</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>61</td> <td>2011/04/25</td> <td>$320,800</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Garrett Winters</td> <td>Accountant</td> <td>Tokyo</td> <td>63</td> <td>2011/07/25</td> <td>$170,750</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Ashton Cox</td> <td>Junior Technical Author</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>66</td> <td>2009/01/12</td> <td>$86,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Cedric Kelly</td> <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>22</td> <td>2012/03/29</td> <td>$433,060</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Airi Satou</td> <td>Accountant</td> <td>Tokyo</td> <td>33</td> <td>2008/11/28</td> <td>$162,700</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Brielle Williamson</td> <td>Integration Specialist</td> <td>New York</td> <td>61</td> <td>2012/12/02</td> <td>$372,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Herrod Chandler</td> <td>Sales Assistant</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>59</td> <td>2012/08/06</td> <td>$137,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Rhona Davidson</td> <td>Integration Specialist</td> <td>Tokyo</td> <td>55</td> <td>2010/10/14</td> <td>$327,900</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Colleen Hurst</td> <td>Javascript Developer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>39</td> <td>2009/09/15</td> <td>$205,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Sonya Frost</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>23</td> <td>2008/12/13</td> <td>$103,600</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jena Gaines</td> <td>Office Manager</td> <td>London</td> <td>30</td> <td>2008/12/19</td> <td>$90,560</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Quinn Flynn</td> <td>Support Lead</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>22</td> <td>2013/03/03</td> <td>$342,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Charde Marshall</td> <td>Regional Director</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>36</td> <td>2008/10/16</td> <td>$470,600</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Haley Kennedy</td> <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td> <td>London</td> <td>43</td> <td>2012/12/18</td> <td>$313,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td> <td>Regional Director</td> <td>London</td> <td>19</td> <td>2010/03/17</td> <td>$385,750</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michael Silva</td> <td>Marketing Designer</td> <td>London</td> <td>66</td> <td>2012/11/27</td> <td>$198,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Paul Byrd</td> <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td> <td>New York</td> <td>64</td> <td>2010/06/09</td> <td>$725,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Gloria Little</td> <td>Systems Administrator</td> <td>New York</td> <td>59</td> <td>2009/04/10</td> <td>$237,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Bradley Greer</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>London</td> <td>41</td> <td>2012/10/13</td> <td>$132,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Dai Rios</td> <td>Personnel Lead</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>35</td> <td>2012/09/26</td> <td>$217,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jenette Caldwell</td> <td>Development Lead</td> <td>New York</td> <td>30</td> <td>2011/09/03</td> <td>$345,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Yuri Berry</td> <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td> <td>New York</td> <td>40</td> <td>2009/06/25</td> <td>$675,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Caesar Vance</td> <td>Pre-Sales Support</td> <td>New York</td> <td>21</td> <td>2011/12/12</td> <td>$106,450</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Doris Wilder</td> <td>Sales Assistant</td> <td>Sidney</td> <td>23</td> <td>2010/09/20</td> <td>$85,600</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Angelica Ramos</td> <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td> <td>London</td> <td>47</td> <td>2009/10/09</td> <td>$1,200,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Gavin Joyce</td> <td>Developer</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>42</td> <td>2010/12/22</td> <td>$92,575</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jennifer Chang</td> <td>Regional Director</td> <td>Singapore</td> <td>28</td> <td>2010/11/14</td> <td>$357,650</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Brenden Wagner</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>28</td> <td>2011/06/07</td> <td>$206,850</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Fiona Green</td> <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>48</td> <td>2010/03/11</td> <td>$850,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Shou Itou</td> <td>Regional Marketing</td> <td>Tokyo</td> <td>20</td> <td>2011/08/14</td> <td>$163,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle House</td> <td>Integration Specialist</td> <td>Sidney</td> <td>37</td> <td>2011/06/02</td> <td>$95,400</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Suki Burks</td> <td>Developer</td> <td>London</td> <td>53</td> <td>2009/10/22</td> <td>$114,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Prescott Bartlett</td> <td>Technical Author</td> <td>London</td> <td>27</td> <td>2011/05/07</td> <td>$145,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Gavin Cortez</td> <td>Team Leader</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>22</td> <td>2008/10/26</td> <td>$235,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Martena Mccray</td> <td>Post-Sales support</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>46</td> <td>2011/03/09</td> <td>$324,050</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Unity Butler</td> <td>Marketing Designer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>47</td> <td>2009/12/09</td> <td>$85,675</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Howard Hatfield</td> <td>Office Manager</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>51</td> <td>2008/12/16</td> <td>$164,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Hope Fuentes</td> <td>Secretary</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>41</td> <td>2010/02/12</td> <td>$109,850</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Vivian Harrell</td> <td>Financial Controller</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>62</td> <td>2009/02/14</td> <td>$452,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Timothy Mooney</td> <td>Office Manager</td> <td>London</td> <td>37</td> <td>2008/12/11</td> <td>$136,200</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td> <td>Director</td> <td>New York</td> <td>65</td> <td>2008/09/26</td> <td>$645,750</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Olivia Liang</td> <td>Support Engineer</td> <td>Singapore</td> <td>64</td> <td>2011/02/03</td> <td>$234,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Bruno Nash</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>London</td> <td>38</td> <td>2011/05/03</td> <td>$163,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td> <td>Support Engineer</td> <td>Tokyo</td> <td>37</td> <td>2009/08/19</td> <td>$139,575</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Thor Walton</td> <td>Developer</td> <td>New York</td> <td>61</td> <td>2013/08/11</td> <td>$98,540</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Finn Camacho</td> <td>Support Engineer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>47</td> <td>2009/07/07</td> <td>$87,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Serge Baldwin</td> <td>Data Coordinator</td> <td>Singapore</td> <td>64</td> <td>2012/04/09</td> <td>$138,575</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Zenaida Frank</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>New York</td> <td>63</td> <td>2010/01/04</td> <td>$125,250</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Zorita Serrano</td> <td>Software Engineer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>56</td> <td>2012/06/01</td> <td>$115,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jennifer Acosta</td> <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>43</td> <td>2013/02/01</td> <td>$75,650</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Cara Stevens</td> <td>Sales Assistant</td> <td>New York</td> <td>46</td> <td>2011/12/06</td> <td>$145,600</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Hermione Butler</td> <td>Regional Director</td> <td>London</td> <td>47</td> <td>2011/03/21</td> <td>$356,250</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Lael Greer</td> <td>Systems Administrator</td> <td>London</td> <td>21</td> <td>2009/02/27</td> <td>$103,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Jonas Alexander</td> <td>Developer</td> <td>San Francisco</td> <td>30</td> <td>2010/07/14</td> <td>$86,500</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Shad Decker</td> <td>Regional Director</td> <td>Edinburgh</td> <td>51</td> <td>2008/11/13</td> <td>$183,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michael Bruce</td> <td>Javascript Developer</td> <td>Singapore</td> <td>29</td> <td>2011/06/27</td> <td>$183,000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Donna Snider</td> <td>Customer Support</td> <td>New York</td> <td>27</td> <td>2011/01/25</td> <td>$112,000</td> </tr> </tbody> <tfoot> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Position</th> <th>Office</th> <th>Age</th> <th>Start date</th> <th>Salary</th> </tr> </tfoot> </table>
```

Comment: I understand , tks you so much !